# how to iterate through model of two table in foreach loop mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the problem for iterating with foreach loop in view of custom model.I am trying to create dynamic menu for razor
Here is my code:

Model:

```
public class MenuCtrlModel

{
    public IList<Menu> menu { get; set; }
    public IList<SubMenu> subMenu { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public PartialViewResult Index()

    {
        var nuser = dataContext.UserLogins.SingleOrDefault(x => x.nvrchrUsername == User.Identity.Name);
        string[] menu = nuser.vcrMenu.ToString().Split('|').ToArray();

        string[] subMenu = nuser.vcrSubmenu.ToString().Split('|').ToArray();

        MenuCtrlModel menuctrl = new MenuCtrlModel();

        menuctrl.menu = (from varMenu in dataContext.Menus where            menu.Contains( Convert.ToString( varMenu.intMenuID ) ) select varMenu).ToList();

        menuctrl.subMenu=(from varSubmenu in dataContext.SubMenus where 
 subMenu.Contains( Convert.ToString(varSubmenu.intSubMenu ) ) select varSubmenu ).ToList();
    }
```

View:
It is giving me error at

```
**@model IList<MVCAPP.Models.MenuCtrlModel>
@foreach(var xyz in Model.select(x=>x.menu))

{

    @Html.RouteLink(xyz.Select(x=>x.nvcrMenuName), new { controller = xyz.Select(x=>x.nvcrLink),action=xyz.Select(x=>x.nvcrLink) })}

}
**
```

I have also tried with

```
@foreach(var xyz in Model)
```

and when I try to find for Menu list like Model.Menu it is not Menu is not appearing in intellisense**
please suggest how can I resolve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry the question is unclear as you have mess in the code formatting. However, can be the problem related to the fact that you have \@model IList instead of \@model MenuCtrlModel?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Model` is a list of `MenuCtrlModel`, each of which has a `menu` property, `Model.select(x=>x.menu)` will return a collection of collections.

I think you want to loop through each item, then loop through the menus in each item:

```
@foreach(var menuModel in Model))
    @foreach(var menu in menuModel.menu))
```

Although I can't tell how the sub-menus are linked to help you any further than that.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need SelectMany because your model is a collection too.

```
@model IList<MVCAPP.Models.MenuCtrlModel>
@foreach(var menu in Model.SelectMany(x => x.Menu))
{
    @Html.RouteLink(menu.nvcrMenuName, new { controller = menu.nvcrLink, action=menu.nvcrLink })
}
```

Alternatively is the `IList<MVCAPP.Models.MenuCtrlModel>` a mistake, your controller codes seems to indicate that you actually have a single `MenuCtrlModel` and so the model line needs correcting?

i.e.

```
@model MVCAPP.Models.MenuCtrlModel
@foreach(var menu in Model.Menu)
{
    @Html.RouteLink(menu.nvcrMenuName, new { controller = menu.nvcrLink, action=menu.nvcrLink })
}
```

Comment: Sir, Problem is not there I am facing problem in this code @Html.RouteLink(link.Select(x=>x.nvcrMenuName), new { controller = link.Select(x=>x.nvcrLink),action=link.Select(x=>x.nvcrLink) })  which comes in foreach loop

Comment: @NadeemShaikh see updated answer, you need to drop the additional selects